# Caddy web server - alias

Tags: webserver, rocket.chat, caddy

There is a Caddy web server in local network listening address https://chat.
A-record (chat - 192.168.10.10) was created in local DNS-server for that local host.

How to configure Caddy for listening https://192.168.10.10:443 as alias?

Current conf file:

```
https://chat {
    bind {$ADDRESS}
    tls /var/snap/rocketchat-server/ssl/chat.crt /var/snap/rocketchat-server/ssl/chat.key
    proxy / localhost:3000 {
    websocket
    transparent
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
192.168.10.10:443{
   redir https://chat{uri}
}
```